# SQL - Sum Aggregate function

Tags: sql, sum

I am fairly new to SQL, so please bare that in mind.

I have have a table with data that is divided into two centers "Toronto & Montreal" for a total of 78 rows (39 per center), with multiple columns. I want to get the national total (sum) of X column for each respective center for a specific daterange (month). For example the Jan 2018 total of full time employees between Montreal + Toronto Centers combined. The logic statement for example would be to add Toronto + Montreal Jan 2018 results to yield me the national total. Although with my beginner skills I am having trouble writing a sql query that can be executed without syntax error.

```
select sum(fte), daterange, center
from (
select  'Toronto' as Center,
        sum(fte) as total fte
from dbo.example
where daterange = '2015-11-01'
group by total fte

union 

select  'Montreal' as Center,
        sum(fte) as total fte
from dbo.example
where daterange = '2015-11-01'
group by total fte
)temptable
group by total fte
```

The above query is giving me a error "Incorrect syntax near 'fte'." fte is a column within my table.

Please advise me what I am doing wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions (e.g. SUM.)

Comment: No need for that UNION. Simple use WHERE to pick the centers. Then GROUP BY center!

Comment: You need to delimit `total fte`, like `'total fte'`

Comment: The query makes no sense . . . "Toronto" and "Montreal" woul dhave the same values.  Also, your table name is `dbo.example`; the `dbo` schema is usually associated with SQL Server and not MySQL.

Comment: I prefer to keep my mind fully clothed, thanks.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
select Center,
  sum(fte) as "[total fte]"
from dbo.example
where daterange = '2015-11-01'
  and Center in ('Toronto','Montreal')
group by Center
```

Understanding that in the attribute Center exist these Strings.

Comment: Just put some quotes around that column alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Center,
  sum(convert(float,fte)) as total_fte
from dbo.example
where daterange = '2016-11-01'
  and Center in ('Toronto','Montreal')
group by Center
```

Works ^ thanks everyone

Comment: You should probably about floats especially since I think these are dollar amounts.